# How to test an intent inside OnBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am developing a news app and want to test an intent started from OnBindViewHolder in my RecyclerViewAdapter class. 
How can I test that activity using Espresso with Kotlin and how can I implement that logic in my testing code?

below RecyclerviewAdapter where I am starting DetailActivity:

```
    class BBCSportAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
        var articleList: List<Article> = listOf()
        companion object {
            const val urlKey = "urlKey"

        }


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bbc_sport_item, null)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

            (holder as ViewHolder).apply {
                when(position){
                    0 -> {
                        header.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE
                        item.visibility = ViewGroup.GONE

                        Picasso.get().load(articleList[position].urlToImage)
                            .into(bigImage)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        header.visibility = ViewGroup.GONE
                        item.visibility = ViewGroup.VISIBLE

                        articleTitle.text = articleList[position].title
                        articleSourceName.text = articleList[position].source.name
                        Picasso.get().load(articleList[position].urlToImage).into(image)
                        val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.getDefault())
                        val output = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                        var d = Date()
                        try {
                            d = input.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
                        } catch (e: ParseException) {
                            try {
                                val fallback = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
                                fallback.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
                                d = fallback.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
                            } catch (e2: ParseException) {

                                val formatted = output.format(d)
                                val timelinePoint = LocalDateTime.parse(formatted)
                                val now = LocalDateTime.now()

                                val elapsedTime = Duration.between(timelinePoint, now)

                                println(timelinePoint)
                                println(now)
                                elapsedTime.toMinutes()

                                articleTime.text = "${elapsedTime.toMinutes()}"


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v->
                val intent = Intent(v.context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("urlKey", articleList[position].url)

                v.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    fun setMovieListItems(articleList: List<Article>) {
        this.articleList = articleList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val image: ImageView = itemView.imageView
        val articleTitle: TextView = itemView.articleTitle
        val articleSourceName: TextView = itemView.articleSourceName
        val imageCategory: ImageView = itemView.imageCategory
        val articleTime: TextView = itemView.articleTime

        val bigImage = itemView.bigImage
        val header: CardView = itemView.header
        val item: CardView = itemView.item
    }
}
```

Below is my Espresso test class where I am trying to implement the intent test logic:

```
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest

class RecyclerViewTest{
@get:Rule
val intentsTestRule = IntentsTestRule(DetailActivity::class.java)


    @Test
    fun testIntent() {
    }

}
```